# ES-head plugin not working through browser

Tags: plugins, elasticsearch, frontend, head

I'm trying to run the elasticSearch-head plugin on my server, but i just can access it through the server terminal. If i try to access it through a browser, it tries to connect until the "This page is not available" browser message is showed.

If i type `"curl -v http://localhost:9200/_plugin/head/"` in the terminal, i get

```
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 9200 (#0)
> GET /_plugin/head/ HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.36.0
> Host: localhost:9200
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 1077
<
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
        <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <title>elasticsearch-head</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/base/reset.css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/vendor.css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/app.css">
                <script src="dist/i18n.js" data-baseDir="dist/lang" data-langs="en,fr,pt"></script>
                <script src="dist/vendor.js"></script>
                <script src="dist/app.js"></script>
                <script>
                        window.onload = function() {
                                if(location.href.contains("/_plugin/")) {
                                        var base_uri = location.href.replace(/_plugin\/.*/, '');
                                }
                                var args = location.search.substring(1).split("&").reduce(function(r, p) {
                                        r[decodeURIComponent(p.split("=")[0])] = decodeURIComponent(p.split("=")[1]); return r;
                                }, {});
                                new app.App("body", {
                                        id: "es",
                                        base_uri: args["base_uri"] || base_uri,
                                        auth_user : args["auth_user"] || "",
                                        auth_password : args["auth_password"],
                                        dashboard: args["dashboard"]
                                });
                        };
                </script>
                <link rel="icon" href="dist/base/favicon.png" type="image/png">
        </head>
        <body></body>
</html>
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

But if i go to a browser and i type: X.X.X.X:9200/_plugin/head/ it just dont show anything.

What im missing here? Any guess?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem. I was using chrome. 
Developer tools in chrome pointed me this error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

One of the suggested [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28848096/351372) on stackoverflow for the above error was to use the below chrome extension to enable and disable CORS on a as needed basis. When this extension was enabled elastic-head started working in chrome.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi/related?hl=en-US

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue after googling for hours I found that you need to restart your elasticsearch nodes but before you do that make sure to shutdown the elasticsearch by running

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/_shutdown
```

Then start your elasticsearch with

```
sudo ./elasticsearch
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found that (at least with the 2.x versions, I can't speak to earlier) you don't need to bounce elasticsearch after installing the head plugin.  The issue for me was that for whatever reason, I couldn't connect over `localhost:9200` but could via my network IP address.  The way I was able to figure this out was via `netstat -na | grep 9200`.

Again, why it chose to do this, I can't confirm - I matched my `/etc/hosts` file with my work desktop and my work desktop doesn't have any issues connecting via `localhost`.

The other thing I had to do was to change was the transport address from `localhost` to my network IP as well or I got a `NoSuchNodeException` on startup.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to create a port tunnel to access it on your local machine - you can do this with putty.

http://howto.ccs.neu.edu/howto/windows/ssh-port-tunneling-with-putty/

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 
I've tried but i get the same result. The browser waits and waits until i get the "This web is not available" :(

Answer (score 0):

Check your proxy settings for the browser. You probably don't want to go through a proxy for local requests. Also check firewall settings on the server and the connecting clients. You didn't specify which browser and platform you are using, so it is hard to provide further help.

Comment: Im using Google chrome, but i tried explorer and firefox. All with windows.
The server uses amazon linux.